# Change closed div button's text

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I have a list of divs that toggles with `toggle()` function. When it toggles, the button that it used to toggle the div change the text from "+" to "-". But when I click to the next button div or the previous button div, the older button didn't change the text with "-" (because is closed, so it should change the text to "-". So I want to change the button's text to "-" if the div is closed.

```js
$(".p1").hide();
$(".p1-venue").hide();
$(".p1-img").hide();
$(".btn1").click(function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) === '+') {
    $(this).text('-');
  } else {
    $(this).text('+');
  }
  var $p1 = $(this).next(".p1").toggle();
  var $p1venue = $(this).parents().next(".p1-venue").toggle();
  var $p1img = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find(".p1-img").toggle();
  $(".p1").not($p1).hide();
  $(".p1-venue").not($p1venue).hide();
  $(".p1-img").not($p1img).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.is(":visible")` like below.

[Click here to find out more](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/)

```js
window.setInterval(() => {
  $(".myDiv").toggle();
}, 1000);

window.setInterval(() => {
  if ($(".myDiv").is(":visible")) {
    $(".text").html("Visible");
  }
  else {
    $(".text").html("Hidden");
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">Visible</p>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```